# Moving from one web form to another web form in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am trying to open webform2 from webform1. I am using sessions to pass the values in between pages, but when I am opening webform2 it is opening in another browser, but I want to open in the current browser only. I wrote the following code for redirecting the page

Webform1.cs code:

```
Session["value"] = Location;  
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx")
```

Webform2.cs page load code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    txtlocation.Text = "" + Session["value"];
}
```

Comment: Using a Response.Redirect should not open a new browser window.  There must be something causing this that you are not showing.

Comment: I think he might be saying that he doesn't want the value to be available in a separate tab.

Comment: ^ Agreed. Sounds like OP is trying to transfer info from one page to another without using a method that stores information across browser instances, like `Session` does.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch you are correct i completely stated this other issue i was facing. coming to above question i am opening a popup window using javascript, after clicking on the select button field in grid view of the popup window the popup window show close and pass that value to the mail browser, but instead of that the popup window is redirecting to the main window. please give a solution for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have the value you want to pass be part of the form, then use Server.Transfer().

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.85).aspx